# React Native Infinite Repeating Images Animation Not in Sync

Tags: react-native, expo

I am attempting to create an infinite parallax background animation in React Native using a set of images. I have successfully created an animation. However, it seems like the longer the animations run, the more they seem unsynced.

Overall, I wrote code which creates three animations in this order:

1. Move the image component y-offset from its initial position to 0.
2. Move the image component y-offset from 0 to -image.height.
3. Move the image component y-offset instantly to the original sum of all image components.
4. Move the image component y-offset to 0 again.
5. Move the image component y-offset to -image.height again.

I put animation sequences 3-5 in a loop so they repeat indefinitely.

I also have the same issue without using Expo. I also thought about having the view position not being absolute so the views would be forced to touch each other. However, with that approach, I would have to re-render when I want to switch my component order.

I have created [this Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@andreyonadam/aW5maW) project to demonstrate what is happening.

Here is a screenshot of the symptom:
[image]

Here is my current code:

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import ScrollingBackground from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollingBackground style={styles.scrollingBackground} images={[require('./assets/chess.png'),require('./assets/chess.png'),require('./assets/chess.png')]}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  scrollingBackground: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});
```

AssetExample.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Animated,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  Easing
} from "react-native";

export default class ScrollingBackground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let imageComponents = [];
    let lastImageYOffset = 0;
    let counter = 0;
    let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    this.props.images.forEach(image => {
      const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);

      let localElement = {};
      let currentKey = "image" + counter.toString();
      localElement.width = width;
      localElement.height = (height * deviceWidth) / width;
      localElement.initialOffset = lastImageYOffset;
      localElement.topPositionAnimated = new Animated.Value(lastImageYOffset);
      localElement.image = image;
      localElement.currentKey = currentKey;
      imageComponents.push(localElement);
      lastImageYOffset = lastImageYOffset + localElement.height;
      counter++;
    });
    lastImageYOffset = lastImageYOffset - imageComponents[imageComponents.length-1].height
    this.setState({
      imageComponents: imageComponents,
      lastImageYOffset: lastImageYOffset
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let animations = [];
    let arrayLength = this.state.imageComponents.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      // let height  = -1 * this.state.imageComponents[i].height
      // this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated.addListener(({value}) => value == height ? console.log(this.state) : "");
      animations.push(
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.timing(this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration:
              10 *
              (this.state.imageComponents[i].initialOffset),
            delay: 0,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
          }),
          Animated.timing(this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated, {
            toValue: -1 * this.state.imageComponents[i].height,
            duration:
              10 *
              (this.state.imageComponents[i].height),
            delay: 0,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true
          }),
          Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
              Animated.timing(this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated, {
                toValue: this.state.lastImageYOffset,
                duration: 0,
                delay: 0,
                useNativeDriver: true
              }),
              Animated.timing(this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration:
                  10 *
                  (this.state.lastImageYOffset),
                delay: 0,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                useNativeDriver: true
              }),
              Animated.timing(this.state.imageComponents[i].topPositionAnimated, {
                toValue: -1 * this.state.imageComponents[i].height,
                duration:
                  10 *
                  (this.state.imageComponents[i].height),
                delay: 0,
                easing: Easing.linear,
                useNativeDriver: true
              }),
            ])
          )
        ])
      );
    }


    Animated.parallel(animations).start();
  }

  render() {
    let elements = [];
    for (imageComponent of this.state.imageComponents) {
      elements.push(
        <Animated.Image
          key={imageComponent.currentKey}
          source={imageComponent.image}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            width: "100%",
            height: imageComponent.height,
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: imageComponent.topPositionAnimated
              }
            ],
            backgroundColor: "white"
          }}
        />
      );
    }
      return (
        <View
          style={[
            styles.container,
            { backgroundColor: this.props.style.backgroundColor }
          ]}
        >
          {elements}
        </View>
      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to latency issues with animating multiple views, animating a container view containing all the individual image views turned out to be the better alternative. I ended up create an react native library for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrolling-images